# How to scrape data from multiple urls to be saved as a single, date ordered csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying this, with a loop defining data to extract for two different urls, yet the exported csv only includes data from the second url:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls=['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2018/',
      'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2019/']

for url in urls:   
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    stats=['game_season', 'date_game', 'age', 'team_id', 'game_location', 'opp_id', 'game_result','gs', 'mp', 'fg',
    'fga', 'fg_pct', 'fg3', 'fg3a', 'fg3_pct', 'ft', 'fta', 'ft_pct', 'orb','drb', 'trb', 'ast', 'stl', 'blk', 'tov', 'pf', 'pts', 'game_score', 'plus_minus']
    stats_left=[[td.getText() for td in soup.findAll('td', {'data-stat': stat})] for stat in stats[:7]]
    stats_right=[[td.getText() for td in soup.findAll('td', {'data-stat': stat})] for stat in stats[7:]]

df_left=pd.DataFrame(stats_left).T
df_left.columns=stats[:7]

for i in range(len(df_left)):
    if df_left['game_season'][i]=="":
        [stats_right[x].insert(i, '') for x in range(len(stats_right))]

df_right=pd.DataFrame(stats_right).T
df_right.columns=stats[7:]
df=pd.concat([df_left, df_right],axis=1)
df.to_csv(r'/Harden_James.csv',index=False)
```

Wondering, how would this work to account for multiple urls and temporarily storing the information?

Answer (score 0):

You kind of answered your own question here. You need to store the dataframe somewhere after each iteration. So what you could do, is just thriw the dataframes into a list, then after the loop, combine those list of dataframes into 1 dataframe.

I'd also consider using `pandas`' `.read_html()`, as you're doing a lot of work constructing the dataframe, when pandas can just do it for you (see Solution 2)

**Solution 1:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls=['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2018/',
      'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2019/']

df_list = []
for url in urls: 
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    stats=['game_season', 'date_game', 'age', 'team_id', 'game_location', 'opp_id', 'game_result','gs', 'mp', 'fg',
    'fga', 'fg_pct', 'fg3', 'fg3a', 'fg3_pct', 'ft', 'fta', 'ft_pct', 'orb','drb', 'trb', 'ast', 'stl', 'blk', 'tov', 'pf', 'pts', 'game_score', 'plus_minus']
    stats_left=[[td.getText() for td in soup.findAll('td', {'data-stat': stat})] for stat in stats[:7]]
    stats_right=[[td.getText() for td in soup.findAll('td', {'data-stat': stat})] for stat in stats[7:]]

    df_left=pd.DataFrame(stats_left).T
    df_left.columns=stats[:7]
    
    for i in range(len(df_left)):
        if df_left['game_season'][i]=="":
            [stats_right[x].insert(i, '') for x in range(len(stats_right))]
    
    df_right=pd.DataFrame(stats_right).T
    df_right.columns=stats[7:]
    df=pd.concat([df_left, df_right],axis=1)
    df_list.append(df)

df = pd.concat(df_list)    
df.to_csv(r'/Harden_James.csv',index=False)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
import pandas as pd

urls=['https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2018/',
      'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/h/hardeja01/gamelog/2019/']

df_list = []
for url in urls: 
    df = pd.read_html(url)[-1]
    df = df[df['Rk'] != 'Rk']
    df_list.append(df)

df = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)    
df.to_csv(r'/Harden_James.csv',index=False)
```

**Output:**

```
print (df)
     Rk    G        Date     Age  ...        PF       PTS      GmSc       +/-
0     1    1  2017-10-17  28-052  ...         2        27      21.6        +1
1     2    2  2017-10-18  28-053  ...         1        27      22.7        +1
2     3    3  2017-10-21  28-056  ...         5        29      20.1       +31
3     4    4  2017-10-23  28-058  ...         4        22       9.5       -14
4     5    5  2017-10-25  28-060  ...         1        27      21.7        +9
5     6    6  2017-10-27  28-062  ...         4        27      22.3        -1
6     7    7  2017-10-28  28-063  ...         3        20      13.7       -13
7     8    8  2017-10-30  28-065  ...         2        29      20.1       -12
8     9    9  2017-11-01  28-067  ...         5        31      16.9       +21
9    10   10  2017-11-03  28-069  ...         0        29      28.5       +19
10   11   11  2017-11-05  28-071  ...         3        56      49.2       +25
11   12   12  2017-11-09  28-075  ...         4        35      35.0        +3
12   13   13  2017-11-11  28-077  ...         3        38      26.6       +23
13   14   14  2017-11-12  28-078  ...         1        26      25.5       +25
14   15   15  2017-11-14  28-080  ...         5        38      23.3        -2
15   16   16  2017-11-16  28-082  ...         3        48      39.4       +15
16   17   17  2017-11-18  28-084  ...         3        29      23.8        +5
17   18   18  2017-11-22  28-088  ...         1        21      13.5       +29
18   19   19  2017-11-25  28-091  ...         1        37      31.3        +2
19   20   20  2017-11-27  28-093  ...         2        37      35.0       +22
20   21   21  2017-11-29  28-095  ...         2        29      26.2       +26
21   22   22  2017-12-03  28-099  ...         3        36      30.1       +11
22   23   23  2017-12-07  28-103  ...         2        29      20.0       +12
23   24   24  2017-12-09  28-105  ...         2        48      38.4        +9
24   25   25  2017-12-11  28-107  ...         3        26      30.8        -2
25   26   26  2017-12-13  28-109  ...         3        21      13.1        -6
26   27   27  2017-12-15  28-111  ...         2        28      20.2       +12
27   28   28  2017-12-16  28-112  ...         4        31      19.7        +1
28   29   29  2017-12-18  28-114  ...         2        26      19.4       +13
29   30   30  2017-12-20  28-116  ...         5        51      37.4        +4
..   ..  ...         ...     ...  ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
134  53   50  2019-02-04  29-162  ...         3        44      37.1       +19
135  54   51  2019-02-06  29-164  ...         4        36      25.4       +16
136  55   52  2019-02-09  29-167  ...         2        42      22.9        -9
137  56   53  2019-02-11  29-169  ...         1        31      25.8        +8
138  57   54  2019-02-13  29-171  ...         2        42      23.9       -14
139  58   55  2019-02-21  29-179  ...         6        30      14.5        -8
140  59  NaN  2019-02-23  29-181  ...  Inactive  Inactive  Inactive  Inactive
141  60   56  2019-02-25  29-183  ...         1        28      14.2        +5
142  61   57  2019-02-27  29-185  ...         2        30      20.4       -14
143  62   58  2019-02-28  29-186  ...         1        58      52.2       +10
144  63   59  2019-03-03  29-189  ...         6        42      26.7       +13
145  64   60  2019-03-05  29-191  ...         4        35      21.6       -10
146  65   61  2019-03-08  29-194  ...         3        31      23.3       +15
147  66   62  2019-03-10  29-196  ...         5        20       3.7        +4
148  67   63  2019-03-11  29-197  ...         3        28      22.7       +11
149  68   64  2019-03-13  29-199  ...         1        29      24.6        +1
150  69   65  2019-03-15  29-201  ...         3        41      38.4        +3
151  70   66  2019-03-17  29-203  ...         4        20      10.4       +20
152  71   67  2019-03-19  29-205  ...         1        31      27.9       +10
153  72   68  2019-03-20  29-206  ...         3        57      44.2       +11
154  73   69  2019-03-22  29-208  ...         3        61      46.0       +18
155  74   70  2019-03-24  29-210  ...         1        28      17.7       +14
156  75   71  2019-03-26  29-212  ...         4        23      11.7       -14
157  76   72  2019-03-28  29-214  ...         2        38      29.9       +14
158  77   73  2019-03-30  29-216  ...         1        50      40.4       +17
159  78   74  2019-04-02  29-219  ...         2        36      33.2       +29
160  79   75  2019-04-03  29-220  ...         3        31      23.5       +16
161  80   76  2019-04-05  29-222  ...         2        26      21.1       +29
162  81   77  2019-04-07  29-224  ...         3        30      28.4       +39
163  82   78  2019-04-09  29-226  ...         4        39      25.0        +1

[164 rows x 30 columns]
```